# 'context has changed since the database was created' issue while deploying to Windows azure

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, entity-framework-migrations

While working in my local, i added two columns in my model. Added migration for it and updated the database. It works fine in my local.

My production server is in windows azure. While deploying, i made sure to check the checkbox of '**Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)**'.  But i am still getting the following error:

> The model backing the 'DataAccess' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

In many blogs i found this solution to be added in `Global.asax`:

```
Database.SetInitializer<Mycontext>(null);
```

But i have already an existing database with many records, so i fear it may initialise my database again. Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the migrations locally against your production database. You'll only need to change the connection string to access your production database.